# Cannot awake from suspend

Tags: 22.04, suspend

I have Razer Blade 15 and Ubuntu 22.04. I'm facing an issue with suspend. Each time the laptop goes to suspend I cannot get it back alive. For example, if I closed the lid and tries to wake it, it shows the login page, lets me log in and after 10 seconds it goes back to suspend automatically.

Specs:

Processor: Intel Core i7-10750H
  GPU: NVIDIA TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile] / Mesa Intel UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
  OS: Ubuntu 22.04
  GNOME: 42.5
  Windowing system: X11

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the output of `journalctl --grep='sleep|suspend|resume' --no-pager --since='-1day'` assuming that issue has occurred at least once in the past ~ 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

If the problem cannot be solved for a long time.
Maybe you can try to keep the system from entering suspend.

Click the Activities button -> Click Settings -> Find power and turn off Automatic Suspend.